# 2008 pt Cruiser Mil Off Spark Ignition

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, chrysler

08 PT Cruiser mil Off Spark Ignition plus p0700 & p0562. The battery & alternator are fine and starter good. I changed the timing belt and afterwords my car would not start. So I got a newer alternator off a 2010 pt cruiser but still won't start. I also changed spark plugs and wires checked ignition coils they are good. What else could be wrong? I'm tired of putting money into a car that won't move. Please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You said you changed the timing belt ... are you SURE you put it back on correctly? Did you try jumping the car? You say it won't run, will it even try to start? Does it crank over (is the starter turning the engine)? Did you check for spark? Is there fuel in the gas tank?

Comment: Definitely check the timing as the next step.

Comment: Do you really mean the timing belt?  Are you really talking about the belt that drives the alternator?

Comment: Did you change the belt yourself?

Comment: This person is not registered ... they're not coming back to answer our questions.